# How to compare specific files in different commits in GIT?

Tags: git, compare, commit

From time to time I need to see the changes of specific files in different commits. Is there any simple way to do this without having to reset & checkout the files and rename to another temporary files?

Answer (score 4):

Try, for example

```
git diff 278d8..1cf1d www/index.html
```

Each of the two hex codes is a unique prefix of the SHA1 hash that identifies a commit.

It's also sometimes helpful to browse differences with `gitk`, but that shows differences between adjacent commits only.

Comment: You can also attach the identifier to the path, like "v1.6:path/to/parent" and "v1.7:its/bastard/child"